# How to find Tomcat's PID and kill it in python?

Tags: python, tomcat, grep, pid, sigkill

Normally, one shuts down Apache Tomcat by running its `shutdown.sh` script (or batch file). In some cases, such as when Tomcat's web container is hosting a web app that does some crazy things with multi-threading, running `shutdown.sh` gracefully shuts down *some* parts of Tomcat (as I can see more available memory returning to the system), but the Tomcat process keeps running.

I'm trying to write a simple Python script that:

1. Calls `shutdown.sh`
2. Runs `ps -aef | grep tomcat` to find any process with Tomcat referenced
3. If applicable, kills the process with `kill -9 <PID>`

Here's what I've got so far (as a prototype - I'm brand new to Python BTW):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Imports
import sys
import subprocess

# Load from imported module.
if __init__ == "__main__":
    main()

# Main entry point.
def main():
    # Shutdown Tomcat
    shutdownCmd = "sh ${TOMCAT_HOME}/bin/shutdown.sh"
    subprocess.call([shutdownCmd], shell=true)

    # Check for PID
    grepCmd = "ps -aef | grep tomcat"
    grepResults = subprocess.call([grepCmd], shell=true)

    if(grepResult.length > 1):
        # Get PID and kill it.
        pid = ???
        killPidCmd = "kill -9 $pid"
        subprocess.call([killPidCmd], shell=true)

    # Exit.
    sys.exit()
```

I'm struggling with the middle part - with obtaining the `grep` results, checking to see if their size is greater than 1 (since `grep` always returns a reference to itself, at least 1 result will always be returned, methinks), and then parsing that returned PID and passing it into the `killPidCmd`. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to replace `grepResults = subprocess.call([grepCmd], shell=true)` with `grepResults = subprocess.check_output([grepCmd], shell=true)` if you want to save the results of the command in grepResults. Then you can use split to convert that to an array and the second element of the array will be the pid: `pid = int(grepResults.split()[1])'`

That will only kill the first process however. It doesn't kill all processes if more then one are open. In order to do that you would have to write:

```
grepResults = subprocess.check_output([grepCmd], shell=true).split()
for i in range(1, len(grepResults), 9):
  pid = grepResults[i]
  killPidCmd = "kill -9 " + pid
  subprocess.call([killPidCmd], shell=true)
```

Comment: Wow - great answer, thanks @Ionut Hulub (+1)! Quick followup - once I have obtain the `pid`, how do I add it to the `killPidCmd`? Can I just use `killPidCmd = "kill -9 $pid` or do I need to use something else? Thanks again!

Comment: Don't forget the space after "kill -9 " :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add "c" to ps so that only the command and not the arguments are printed. This would stop grab from matching its self.

I'm not sure if tomcat shows up as a java application though, so this may not work.

PS: Got this from googling: "grep includes self" and the first hit had that solution.

EDIT: My bad! OK something like this then?

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["ps caux | grep tomcat"], shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
out.split()[1] #<-- checkout the contents of this variable, it'll have your pid!
```

Basically "out" will have the program output as a string that you can read/manipulate

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Sandro (+1) - however that does not answer my question. I'm trying to parse the results from grep, use it to obtain a variable `pid`, and then pass `pid` into the `killPidCmd` so that it can be executed on the shell. Any thoughts - and thanks again!

Comment: Ah, ok sorry I didn't understand the problem, checkout my edit.

Comment: Thanks again @Sandro - can you take a look at my comment underneath Ionut Hulub's answer - I have the same question for you!

Comment: "kill -9 " + str(pid) --or-- ("kill -9 %d" % pid) either will do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Creating child processes to run `ps` and string match the output with `grep` is not necessary. Python has great string handling 'baked in' and Linux exposes all the needed info in /proc.  The procfs mount is where the command line utilities get this info.  Might as well go directly to the source.

```
import os

SIGTERM = 15

def pidof(image):
    matching_proc_images = []
    for pid in [dir for dir in os.listdir('/proc') if dir.isdigit()]:
        lines = open('/proc/%s/status' % pid, 'r').readlines()
        for line in lines:
            if line.startswith('Name:'):
                name = line.split(':', 1)[1].strip()
                if name == image:
                    matching_proc_images.append(int(pid))

    return matching_proc_images


for pid in pidof('tomcat'): os.kill(pid, SIGTERM)
```